# Start css3 animation when the content is visible

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, scroll

I've made an animation using svg and now I wonder how to activate it when it shows on the screen. Tried with Scroll Reveal but it doesn't work.

Here is the animation: http://jsfiddle.net/z86026mv/148/light/

HTML

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="136.5px" height="100.15px" viewBox="0 0 136.5 100.15" enable-background="new 0 0 136.5 100.15" xml:space="preserve">
  <rect class="key" x="111.284" y="80.95" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="1.02" height="1.02"/>
  <path class="phone" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M102.85 31.275L90.902 43.222v51.003h29.837l11.947-11.946V31.275H102.85z"/>
  <polyline class="bottom_line" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="52.476 94.225 65.188 94.225 78.059 94.225 "/>
  <line class="vert_line" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="65.188" y1="94.225" x2="65.188" y2="81.969"/>
  <polyline class="screen" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="120.74 22.27 120.74 5.924 3.813 5.924 3.813 81.969 82.262 81.969 "/>
```

CSS

```
/*Animacje*/
svg * {
    fill: none;
    stroke: currentColor;
    stroke-linecap: square;
    stroke-linejoin: miter;
    color: #100F0D;
    stroke-width: 6;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
.phone {
  animation: draw 1.5s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) alternate;
  -webkit-animation: draw 1.5s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) alternate;
}

@keyframes draw {

    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 192;
    stroke-dasharray: 192;
  }
    100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 192;
  }
}
.screen {
    animation: screen 1.5s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) alternate;
    -webkit-animation: screen 1.5s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) alternate;
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 6;
}

@keyframes screen {

    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 290;
    stroke-dasharray: 290;
  }
    100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 290;
  }
}

.bottom_line {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: bottom_line 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) 1s forwards;
       -moz-animation: bottom_line 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) 1s forwards;
         -o-animation: bottom_line 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) 1s forwards;
            animation: bottom_line 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes bottom_line {

    0% {
    opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 290;
    stroke-dasharray: 290;
  }
    100% {
    opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 290;
  }
}
.vert_line{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: vert_line 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) 1s forwards;
       -moz-animation: vert_line 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) 1s forwards;
         -o-animation: vert_line 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) 1s forwards;
            animation: vert_line 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 0, 0.87) 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes vert_line {

    0% {
    opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 290;
    stroke-dasharray: 290;
  }
    100% {
    opacity: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 290;
  }
}

.key {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: key 1s ease 1s forwards;
       -moz-animation: key 1s ease 1s forwards;
         -o-animation: key 1s ease 1s forwards;
            animation: key 1s ease 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes key {

    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(-35px,0px);
        -ms-transform: translate(-35px,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(-35px,0px); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform: translate(-35px,0px); /* Opera */
        -moz-transform: translate(-35px,0px); /* Firefox */

    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0,0px);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,0px); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0px); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform: translate(0,0px); /* Opera */
        -moz-transform: translate(0,0px); /* Firefox */
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes key {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;

    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

And here, in the "Service" section I have placed it. `http://flowagency.nu/index_ico.php`

Do you have any ideas?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Downvoted because you're TOLD to include the code. But no, you're trying to workaround it by mimicking the links for the code :/

Comment: @nicael Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the display of the svg to none `var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
svg.style.display='none';` then when you click on the service tab you can set the display to block `svg.style.display='block';` watch out the example below i did the second step using `setTimeout` you can do it with click or whatever you like

http://jsfiddle.net/z86026mv/149/

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't work. I have placed a block to have the possibility to scroll down, but the animation is gone. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/z86026mv/151/)

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/z86026mv/155/  you have to get the position of the div  and you have to detect the position of the page while you scrolling and compare them together so when the div is shown you set the display to `block`

Comment: It works, thank you. Can you help with one more thing? I want the animation once, can you do that? Thx again.

Comment: Just remove the second if statement